# Rails link_to only works on some pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got this line in my view:

```
<%= link_to (t "user.password_forgott", :controller => :users, :action => :passwordLost) %>
```

When I call the popup where the link is from different pages only a page that is renderet from users controller the link appears, else the href="" is empty

whats the problem?

[image]

Comment: @MrNagoo it is alias `translate()`. [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api)

Comment: yes its for translation, the text is not the problem, is shown all the time, the href is empty

Comment: added a picture above how <a> looks like when link is not rendered

Comment: Show us the route and controller name/method you are trying to get. You might be coming from other languages, but snake_case is preferred to camelCase when naming methods.

Comment: Your syntax is effectively passing `:controller => :users, :action => :passwordLost` as additional arguments to `t`, not `link_to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `link_to(t("user.password_forgott"), {:controller => :users, :action => :passwordLost})`

Comment: `t("user.password_forgott")` is the important change, you can remove the other parentheses and the curly braces.

Comment: @Stefan I suggested the curly braces, because link_to takes two hashes for url_options and html_options - using the curly braces just makes it explicit that the controller and action are url_options.

Comment: I see. A named route (e.g. `password_lost_path`) would be even better - it removes that ambiguity.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I agree - using the named route is even better.